# select data from ms access database by date in c#

Tags: c#, database, date, ms-access-2013

i want to select data from ms  access database in c# i use this query

```
da = new OleDbDataAdapter(
    "SELECT [Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Date] from [Total] Where [Date] between #" 
        + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString() 
        + "# AND #" 
        + dateTimePicker3.Value.ToString() 
        + "#", 
    VCON);
```

it's return me null 
please help me.

Comment: @Leopard: That's the date/time delimiter in Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must format date like :

```
dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

you can also do :

```
da = new OleDbDataAdapter(
        "SELECT [Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Date] from [Total] Where [Date] between "
            + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("#yyyy/MM/dd#")
            + " AND "
            + dateTimePicker3.Value.ToString("#yyyy/MM/dd#") ,
        VCON);
```

But, I advice you to use the Parameter to avoid SQL injections , like this :

```
string query = "SELECT [Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Date] from [Total] Where [Date] " +
               "BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, VCON);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate ", DbType.DateTime).Value = 
                                            dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate ", DbType.DateTime).Value = 
                                            dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
```